# Work done in space

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work

What is the work done if we apply a force on body and body is displaced through a distance, but the condition is that the above activity is performed in space where there is no other force is present?

Comment: Same as if a force is applied over a distance anywhere else.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand the motivation for this question.  By stipulation, there is no other force present and so, trivially, the *net* force is just the stipulated applied force.  Am I missing something?

Comment: How are you applying this force?

Comment: -1 What is your difficulty?  What difference does th absence of other forces make? Isn't this situation easier to understand?

Comment: In physics I have always encountered phrases such as work done against something; so If there would nothing be in against the what would be the work..#sammy gerbil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of work is, mathematically, given some force ($\vec{F}$) and some path or distance ($C$) and its infinitesimal part of such path or distance($d\vec{s}$), all of which incorprioates their directions (i.e. their vector property):

$$ W = \int_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s} $$

That is, if there is no force, then there is no work. In your particular scenario, there is other no force, so, therefore, there is no work (as Alfred Centauri's comment) other than that applied by the given force. Your force vector acts, mathematically, like all other force vectors. The amount of work done is still formulated in the same way, just with the force that you are talking about.

The work equation always assumes the net force vector; again in your case, there is only one force vector, so, the net force and your force is the same force vector.